# Remove trailing 0 from function that is used both statically and dynamically

Tags: ajax

I have a template part with lots of html that I use both to add statically and dynamically to a page. The problem is the trailing 0 when adding with ajax which we get rid of using die() but that cuts off all content below when the function is added statically.

Comment: its better to create a function that create the output. then in AJAX you call the function and end with "exit()" and in the template, you just use the function.

Comment: That definitely works